# How to do scrape a file downloaded via <a onclick="openDownload()" href="#">?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a file from here: https://www.msci.com/end-of-day-history?chart=regional&priceLevel=41&scope=R&style=C&currency=15&size=36&indexId=13

The file is downloaded via button on top of the website, which, upon inspection of the html seems to be:

```
<a onclick="openDownload()" href="#">
```

I am able to manually download the file, however, I have no idea how to do it via Python and its libraries. Any idea how to bypass this?
Thanks.

Comment: This is too broad/vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link  calls the function openDownload() on click.

You can go to your browser console and type openDownload (without brackets) to see the code for that function. 
In your case it grabs the download link attribute from a graph and sets window.location to that (which redirects you).

```js
function openDownload() {
                 var chart = document.getElementById("perfChart");
          var href = chart.urlForDownload();
          window.location = href;
      }
```

You can find that download url and use that directly from your python code.

Comment: Couldn't grab the exact link for you as my browser doesnt render that graph. Assuming it does for you then you can grab the url this way (just console.log the urlForDownload() value)

Comment: Thank you. I have never done it before, so I assume I should go to console (F12 in Chrome) and type in: console.log(urlForDownload()). When I do this, I get: Uncaught ReferenceError: urlForDownload is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:9

Comment: Alright, got it. I opened the console and clicked the download button and the direct link to the data appeared in the console.

Comment: you can run the opendownload function code manually and replace the window.localtion to a console.log statement